# Javascript: A dictionary of functions; one function in dictionary calls another

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

I have a dictionary of functions which are essentially different calls to an API I am using to receive data (in promises). The way my API has structured its data, in order to get every species from each country, I must make a call to the API modifying the https request, using a keyword `q` which is specific to each country. I have created an function within the dictionary called `sp_b_c`, which means species by country. It takes an `q`, which is the country, where the call itself returns a promise with a promise value of all the species within that country.

I want to create another function in the dictionary which would allow me to grab all species from each country so that it all will be contained for later use.

What I have attempted to do is to create a new function called `sp_b_c_all`. I make a call to my `country_list` function in the dictionary to obtain all of the countries. I then iterate through each country and pass each country into the function `sp_b_c`. I have created an array `sp_b_c_entire` which essentially acts like a Promise.all, because all of the promises received by iterating through countries and passing each country into a call for `sp_b_c` results in a returned promise.

However, when making this call `getData("accesses", "sp_b_c_all")]`,
I receive the following error:

```
script.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: country_li.then is not a function
    at Object.accesses.sp_b_c_all (script.js:38)
    at getData (script.js:68)
    at initialization (script.js:194)
    at script.js:365
```

Below is the code this is referring to:

```
var getData = function(set, target, q, ...manyMore) {
  var pack = [];
  // ~ USE rest parameters instead, grab array from ...

  // set accesses
  var api_token = "9d34bf3f79ae6a8b88c4f1f54ffc3e64e5f4cdcc2cc47bd1cf429e7e247d94b2";
  var accesses = new Object();
  var alternative = new Object();

  // ~ do a promise all, might be overload for API, so limitations
  if (set == "accesses") {
   accesses.sp_b_c = function(q) {
     return d3.json("https://apiv3.iucnredlist.org/api/v3/country/getspecies/"+ q +
     "?token=9d34bf3f79ae6a8b88c4f1f54ffc3e64e5f4cdcc2cc47bd1cf429e7e247d94b2")
     .then(function(d) { return d; });
   }

   accesses.sp_b_c_all = function() {
     sp_b_c_entire = [];
     console.log(accesses.sp_b_c("AE"))
     var country_li = accesses.country_list;
     country_li.then(function(countries) {
       console.log(countries);
       countries.forEach(function(country) {
         sp_b_c_entire.push(accesses.sp_b_c(country));
       })
    })
    return sp_b_c_entire;
  }

   accesses.country_list = function() {
     return d3.json("https://apiv3.iucnredlist.org/api/v3/country/list?token="+api_token)
              .then(function(d) { return d; });
   }
   accesses.comp_group_list = function() {
     return d3.json("https://apiv3.iucnredlist.org/api/v3/comp-group/list?token="+api_token)
              .then(function(d) { return d; });
   }
   accesses.comp_group_specific = function() {
     return d3.json("https://apiv3.iucnredlist.org/api/v3/comp-group/getspecies/"+ key +"?token="+api_token)
              .then(function(d) { return d; });
   }
   accesses.threats_regional = function() {
     return d3.json("http://apiv3.iucnredlist.org/api/v3/threats/species/name/Ursus%20maritimus/region/europe?token="+api_token)
              .then(function(d) { return d; });
   }
   accesses.threats_global = function() {
     return d3.json("http://apiv3.iucnredlist.org/api/v3/threats/species/name/Loxodonta%20africana?token="+api_token)
              .then(function(d) { return d; });
   }

   return accesses[target]();
 }
  // alternative threat dataset
  else if (set == "csv") {
    var data = d3.csv(target + ".csv");
    var transformation = data.then(
      function(d) {
        var container = d.map(function(d) {
        return {s_n: d.ScientificName,
                c_n: d.CommonName,
                state: d.States,
                group: d.group};
        });
        pack.push(container);
      } // end of anon/callback function
    ); // end of then function
  return data;
  } // end of else if conditional


};
```

I had thought if I made the call `accesses.country_list` from within `accesses.sp_b_c_all` that I would receive the promise for the country list. I then utilize `then()` to access the promise value. Inside of `then(countries)`, countries is the dataset (the list of countries. This is where I utilize a forEach loop to iterate through each country in `countries`, and then I pass each country into the api call for `accesses.sp_b_c`with the country parameter. From this, I hope to receive a promise, and then store it in the array.

What am I doing wrong and how might I fix this? How should I alter my though process, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `country_li` is a function that returns a promise, you need to call it first to get that promise:

```
country_li().then(function(countries) {...})
```

Comment: so by saying, ```accesses.country_li``` I am only grabbing the function stored within without ever calling it?

Comment: Yes exactly @MichaelRamage - `typeof country_li == "function"`.